# Contact Form Animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, contact-form-7

I have the following code:

```css
input[type=text], [type=email], select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}


.contactform {
  position: relative;    
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index:2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom:auto;
  margin-top:1%;    
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
    
}
    
.contactform:hover { 
 animation-name: gradient;
 animation-duration: 15s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;    
       
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;    
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column, input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top:0;
  }
}
```

```html
 <section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2><br/>Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="thankyou.html" method="POST">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="first name" name="firstname" placeholder="Your firstname.." required>

            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required>

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>

            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate..." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

So what I am basically looking for is the shake effect when the user submits without entering any inputs.

### Expected Output

When the user hits the submit button without entering anything, the border of the box should turn red as well as shake. I just want the boxes of the placeholders to shake and turn red, not the whole element. I tried adding keyframes to make this possible but got stuck since I was not getting the desired output, any suggestions?

In other words, I just would like the `first name`, `last name`, `email`, and `subject` borders of the boxes to turn red and shake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event listener for `submit` that loops through all the input and textarea fields and checks whether they are valid with `checkValidity()`. If they are not valid, we set their border color to red with the `borderColor` style attribute and set their animation with the `animation` style attribute.

To be able to play the same animation over and over again, we can use `setTimeout` to wait a specified number of milliseconds and then set the `animation` style attribute back to `unset`.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  var isValid = true;
  this.querySelectorAll('input, textarea').forEach(function(f) {
    if (!f.checkValidity()) {
      isValid = false;
      f.style.borderColor = "red";
      f.style.animation = "shake 0.82s forwards";
      setTimeout(function(){f.style.animation="unset";},820);
    }else{
      f.style.borderColor = "initial";
      //Sets it back to normal if the field is valid
    }
  })
  if (!isValid) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```css
input[type=text],
[type=email],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.contactform {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.contactform:hover {
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column,
  input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2><br/>Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="thankyou.html" method="POST" novalidate>
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="first name" name="firstname" placeholder="Your firstname.." required>

            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required>

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>

            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate..." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves it! I thought there was also a way with css but I never thought of the js solution

Comment: You could look for the animationend event instead of having to set a timeout.